# Excel: Get number of rows after last row containing substring

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a pity counter using an Excel formula. Here are the steps needed to get the pity value:

1. Get the highest index of the row that contains the text "(Legendary)" (row 4)
2. Get the highest index of a row that contains any text (row 6)
3. Subtract the indexes to get the number of rows since the last Legendary (6 - 4 = 2)

```
             A               B
1    Sword (Rare)            2
2    Bow   (Legendary)
3    Sword (Rare)
4    Sword (Legendary)
5    Sword (Rare)
6    Magic (Rare)
```

How can I write a formula that will set `B1` to the number of rows since the last Legendary item?

Comment: QQ - Is it possible to split column A? For eg Sword in column A, Rare in column B?

Comment: @pykam No, values are copied directly from the game and are part of the item name. Since there are thousands of rows separating them would be a prohibitive effort.

Comment: In Microsoft365, you could use `=COUNTA(A:A)-XMATCH("*(Legendary)",A:A,2,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=COUNTA(A:A)-MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND("(Legendary)",A:A)),"",ROW(A:A)))`.  If your version of Excel doesn't support dynamic arrays, you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use an array formula.  This assumes there are no blanks in your list.